# Loading values from a column in a database into radiobuttons

Tags: php, html, radio-button

I've a HTML form with **30** lines of radio buttons. Each line, or a set, contains 3 radiobuttons. I need to assign every line of the radio button the values - `0` (goes to the first radiobutton), `1` (goes to the second radiobutton), `2` (goes to the third radiobutton) - from a particular column in my database.

**SQL**

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<strong>def is</strong>'.$row['def'].'<br/>';
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="radio" 
       id="question1A" 
       value="0"
       name="question1A"
       <?php echo ($row['def']) ? 'checked' : ''?> >
```

**Assumptions**

- SQL Statement is correct. Not sure if it matters, but I'm selecting two tables in the statement.
- The column `def` values `0`, `1` and `2` appear in an arbitrary order e.g. 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2 ...  and all other possible combinations.

Appreciate your assistance. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check for each radiobutton in a radiobutton group (question1) to add the checked attribute.

```
<input type="radio" 
       id="question1" 
       value="0"
       name="question1A"
       <?php $row['def'] == 0 ? 'checked' : ''?> >

<input type="radio" 
       id="question1" 
       value="1"
       name="question1B"
       <?php $row['def'] == 1 ? 'checked' : ''?> >

<input type="radio" 
       id="question1" 
       value="2"
       name="question1C"
       <?php $row['def'] == 2 ? 'checked' : ''?> >
```